# Как сделать сдвиг сохраняя индекс?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть DataFrame:

```
Товар   Дата         Продажи    
 a      2014-01-01   100
 a      2014-01-02   150
 b      2014-01-01   305
 b      2014-01-02   100
 c      2014-01-01   110
```

Нужно получить следующий DataFrame:

```
Товар   Дата        Продано    Продано 1 день назад
a       2014-01-01   100        NaN
a       2014-01-02   150        100
b       2014-01-01   305        NaN
b       2014-01-02   100        305
c       2014-01-01   110        NaN
```

Я пытаюсь через `groupby`, но это не работает:

```
df['Продано 1 день назад']=df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0), 'Продано']).shift()
```

Comment: `Товар` - это индекс или обычный столбец? PS если в вашем реальном DF используется multi-index, то это надо отобразить в прмере входных и выходных данных. Решения работающие для обычных индексов скорее всего не будут правильно работать для DF с multi-index

Comment: В таблице нет multi-index, Товар - это Int64Index, name='Товар'.

Comment: Похоже у вас устаревшая версия Pandas...

Comment: т.е. мое решение должно работать?

Comment: нет, ваше решение нерабочее - в моем ответе я указал оба рабочих варианта (первый будет работать для последних версий, второй - и для старых весрий тоже)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [47]: df
Out[47]:
  Товар        Дата  Продано
0     a  2014-01-01      100
1     a  2014-01-02      150
2     b  2014-01-01      305
3     b  2014-01-02      100
4     c  2014-01-01      110

In [48]: df['Продано 1 день назад'] = df.groupby('Товар')['Продано'].shift()

In [49]: df
Out[49]:
  Товар        Дата  Продано  Продано 1 день назад
0     a  2014-01-01      100                   NaN
1     a  2014-01-02      150                 100.0
2     b  2014-01-01      305                   NaN
3     b  2014-01-02      100                 305.0
4     c  2014-01-01      110                   NaN
```

---

**UPDATE:** если `Товар` - это индекс, а не обычный столбец:

```
In [57]: df
Out[57]:
             Дата  Продано
Товар
a      2014-01-01      100
a      2014-01-02      150
b      2014-01-01      305
b      2014-01-02      100
c      2014-01-01      110
```

для последних версий Pandas предыдущее решение будет работать правильно если индекс имеет наименование `Товар`:

```
In [55]: df.groupby('Товар')['Продано'].shift()
Out[55]:
Товар
a      NaN
a    100.0
b      NaN
b    305.0
c      NaN
Name: Продано, dtype: float64
```

более старые версии Pandas не различают индекс по его имени - в этом случае стоит использовать следующий подход:

```
In [58]: df.groupby(level=0)['Продано'].shift()
Out[58]:
Товар
a      NaN
a    100.0
b      NaN
b    305.0
c      NaN
Name: Продано, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Столбец "Товар" и есть индекс.